# GPIO 19 always on even after shutdown - Troubleshoot tips?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w

Connected a LED to GPIO 19 (Pi Zero W) and it is always on, only turns off when I disconnect the power.

Even after the shutdown command, stills on.

```
$ sudo shutdown now
```

Ran the code below and it didn't turnoff

```
from gpiozero import LED
led = LED(19)
while True:
   led.off()
```

Start to under if my PI is busted. Any troubleshoot tips?

Edit:
[image: photo of the wiring]

Comment: Post a photo of your wiring.

Comment: Also be aware that shutdown does not switch off power to the GPIO.  They stay in the last set state.

Comment: Photo of the wiring - https://imgur.com/a/J1Tx42J

Comment: PIN#1 is next to the SDCard slot. It has a the SQUARE pad on the underside of the board. Nothing is connected to PIN#19 in your photo.  You have a wire on 
 PIN#2 & PIN#6. https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin35_gpio19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have wired your LED and resistor to 5V (physical pin 2) and GND (physical pin 6).

You should be using GPIO19 (physical pin 35) and any GND pin.

https://pinout.xyz/